# Cannot create new angular project

Tags: angular

I am new in angular, When i just run `ng new prj-name` command in specific folder i get following error message:

### Error:

```
npm ERR!
enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
rename 'Desktop\angular\angular-intro\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript' ->
'Desktop\angular\angular-intronode_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\.typescript.DELETE' 
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I have following Version of node and angular on my computer:

### Version:

```
C:\Users\lin0x\Desktop\angular>node -v
v9.9.0
C:\Users\lin0x\Desktop\angular>ng -v

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 9.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

now paste this in cmd it should work. you might not install globally

and [visit here](https://cli.angular.io/) for better guide.

Comment: as i mentioned in question i've installed angular with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, But in creation step when i run `ng new prj-name` i get error!

Comment: @linux just try this once [sudo] `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` 
`npm cache clean`
[sudo] `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then install again:)

Comment: I am on windows OS, should i run cmd as administrator instead of linux sudo ?

Comment: no need to run as administrator. just hit command directly it will uninstall cli globally

Comment: @linux if its work please accept my answer. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately i get same error message while running `ng new app-name` as i mentioned in question :(

Comment: you also did `npm cache clean`

Comment: Yes i did, before i completely uninstalled node and angular and re installed all of those but problem not solved.

Comment: bro only solution is complete uninstall and then latest install. that's it. do again until it works fine :)